# cake php form containing file upload not adding enctype="multipart/form-data" attribute

Tags: php, forms, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a controller Job and controller User
I want to send post data from the view of Job Controller  to User controller 
the form contains file upload option too

```
$this->Form->create('User',array('url'=>array('controller'=>'Users','action'=>'newUser')),array('type' =>'file','enctype'=>'multipart/form-data'))
```

it will give the out put

```
<form action="/User/newUser" id="UserViewForm" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
```

but it is not adding attribute of `enctype="multipart/form-data"
to form`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
$this->Form->create('User', 
array('type' => 'file', 'class' => 'classname', 'url'=>array('controller'=>'Users','action'=>'newUser') ) );
```

You don't need to create a separate array for the all options.

Docs: [Form Options](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#options-for-create)

Comment: this is working fine just one thing i want to know is 
i want to add panel class to the form where to add?

Comment: I added the class name too. If this helps you can accept the answer as correct :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
echo $this->Form->create('User', array('url' => array('controller' => 'Users','action' =>'newUser'),'class'=>'classname','enctype'=>'multipart/form-data')); 
?>
```